# A question about the multiplication rule of probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

For a probability of the form P(A) x P(B|A), does the P(B|A) part express the probability of event B given **ONLY** event A? Does this probability completely ignore the other factors and events, especially in a complex scenario, and treat them like they don’t exist?

Simply using the multiplication rule of probability in a realistic scenario doesn’t seem to make sense. For example, let’s say I want to find the probability of me both passing the exam and being happy. From what I learned, this would be expressed as :

P(Passing exam) x P(Being happy | Passing exam)

It seems reasonable that the second part of this expression is a high probability and, let’s just say the probability of the first part is also high :) This should, supposedly, give me the probability of both passing the exam and being happy. But here’s the thing: **there are so many other factors that we need to consider!** I can’t just ignore these, right? So my question is really just about whether or not this supposed probability **assumes no other given factors besides “passing exam” or, to put it generally, the given factor**.

Comment: The "other factors" are what we are modeling as "random" when we think about this in terms of probabilities. If we knew all the factors, we would know the outcome and we wouldn't have to talk about probabilities.

Comment: @3rdMoment these are called “random variables” in statistics right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\mathbb P(B\vert A)$ is the probability of $B$ in an alternate universe where you have discarded any outcome that does not belong to $A$.

I am not sure to understand your concern. What do you mean by there are many other factors that we need to consider? Do you mean that it's not that easy to pass the exam? In that case your P(passing exam) would not be that high. Or do you mean that it is not that trivial to be happy just because you passed the exam? In that case your P(Being happy | Passing exam) would not be as high as you say it is.

Maybe you get confused between P(Being happy | Passing exam) and P(Being happy of passing exam).

Comment: “Or do you mean that it is not that trivial to be happy just because you passed the exam? In that case your P(Being happy | Passing exam) would not be as high as you say it is.” But see, if that was the case, wouldn’t we be considering other factors for happiness (say for example health and wealth) before even using happiness as the given factor? Wouldn’t that also contradict what we just established, that P(B|A) is the probability of B given only and only A?

Comment: Why would these factors disappear? You have scenarios where you are in good health and pass the exams, others where you are in good health and fail the exam, same with bad health. If you believe for instance that good health is much more relevant to happiness than passing the exams, then the scenarios of good health in the branch "exam passed" and scenarios of good health in the branch "exam failed" have similar impact on your happiness, in which case you can "cut a branch" and select only the "exam passed" one, it would not affect much your probability of finding happiness.

Comment: Hmm… Ok I think I get the gist of it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, let's say there are **only** three factors there are related to your level of happiness: passing an exam, sleeping well, and having good friends. In this case, the probability that you will be happy is:

P(being happy|passing an exam)P(passing an exam)+P(being happy|sleeping well)P(sleeping well) + P(being happy|having good friends)P(having good friends)

In this way you take into account all the factors that make you happy and nothing is missing out.